# Android (share button) crash in startActivity for Intent.createChooser works with most of phones except pixel

Tags: android, android-intent, share-intent

I'm doing app to share a png image to facebook and all, the code works fine in my Huawei Honor 8 and crashes with the google pixel 2. 
code:

```
showLoading("Saving...");
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + ""
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
photoEditorView.getSource().setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/png");
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
```

Comment: `Android (share button) crash in startActivity` Where is your crash log? you need to share your crash log with question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: thanks, i think my bug was only because the phone has no external storage tray not as the main problem of saving and sharing button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
File nFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
                    Uri mmuri;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        mmuri = getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",nFile);
                    } else{
                        mmuri = Uri.fromFile(nFile);
                    }
```

using mmuri uri for sending image.

add in manifest

```
<provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="your package name.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
            </provider>
```

in res make xml folder and create provider_paths.xml  file and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: you nailed it from the provider paths, never know that i can provide 2 paths , and yeah it works , thanks a lot you saved my day :)